# Images in my github project wont show in github pages, I've tried 5 different ways to fix it, but it didnt work

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I'm trying to link the images in my project to the index.html, but github pages wont show them. Ive tried many ways to link it, but it simply wont work.

Each time I update the index.html file with the new trial, I wait for the new deploy before checking out the page.

I searched a lot before posting here, any solutions I found simply didnt work.

The ways I tried to reference the images, that didnt work, are as bellow:

This is my repository: https://github.com/lauraperroni/site-portfolio-curso

This is the file tree:

```
site-portfolio-curso
    icons
        coracao.svg
        github.svg  
        instagram.svg
        linkedin.svg
        icons8-heart-48.png
        
    img
        eu.jpeg
    styles
        style.css
README.md
index.html
```

For:

```
<img class="perfil__foto" src="https://github.com/lauraperroni/site-portfolio-curso/blob/main/img/eu.jpeg" alt="foto da autora">
```

I've tried:

```
src="img/eu.jpeg"   
src="/img/eu.jpeg"      
src="./img/eu.jpeg"         
src="../img/eu.jpeg"        
src="https://github.com/lauraperroni/site-portfolio-curso/blob/main/img/eu.jpeg"
src="site-portfolio-curso/img/eu.jpeg"
```

For:

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/lauraperronigtr" class="header__link" title="Me acompanhe no Instagram" target=”_blank”><img class="icon" src="../icons/instagram.svg" alt="instagram"></a>
```

I've tried:

```
src="/icons/instagram.svg"
src="./icons/instagram.svg"
src="../icons/instagram.svg"
src="https://github.com/lauraperroni/site-portfolio-curso/blob/main/icons/instagram.svg"
src="site-portfolio-curso/icons/instagram.svg"
```

There are 2 more icons for my github and linkedin but they look and are linked the same as the instagram one.

Answer (score -1):

I made it work by using the full link:

```
src="/site-portfolio-curso/img/eu.jpeg"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).